# update column value alphabets to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Alphabet A to Z in my Key Column and want to update them and set numeric,
ex:A=001 and B=002 and so on.
How to write the logic in sql query.

Comment: `REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )` update x set column = replace(column,'A','001') ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186862.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ASCII T-SQL function, and RIGHT to pad-left it:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET [KeyCol] = RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3), ASCII([keyCol]) - ASCII('A') + 1), 3)
```

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is good for when you don't have SQL Server around.

Comment: @TT. Yes! How could I miss that?!!